# Timing overhead binary semaphore vs mutex

Tags: c++, mutex, semaphore, vxworks

I have run a sample C++ program on vxWorks platform to test the timing difference between mutex and a binary semaphore. The below program is the prototype

```
SEM ID semMutex;
UINT ITER = 10000;
taskIdOne = TASKSPAWN("t1",TASK_PRIORITY_2,0,8192,0,(FUNCPTR)myMutexMethod,0,0);
taskIdTwo = TASKSPAWN("t2",TASK_PRIORITY_2,0,8192,0,(FUNCPTR)myMutexMethod,0,0);
void myMutexMethod(void)
    {
        int i;
        VKI_PRINTF("I'm  (%s)\n",TASKNAME(0) );
        myMutexTimer.start();
        for (i=0; i < ITER; i++)
        {
            MUTEX_LOCK(semMutex,WAIT_FOREVER); 
            ++global;                     
            MUTEX_UNLOCK(semMutex); 
        } 
        myMutexTimer.stop();
        myMutexTimer.show();
    }
```

In the above program there is a contention ( 2 tasks are trying to get the mutex). my timer printed 37.43 ms  for the above program. With the same prototype, binary semaphore program took just 2.8 ms.  This  is understood because binary semaphore is lightweight  and does not have many features like a mutex (priority inversion, ownership etc).

However, I removed one task and ran the above program ( without contention).  Since there is no contention, the task t1 just gets the mutex , executes the critical section and then releases the mutex. Same with Binary semaphore.
For the timings, mutex I got 3.35 ms and binary semaphore  4 ms.

I'm surprised to see mutex is faster than binary semaphore when there is no contention.
Is this expected?  or am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated. !

Comment: I think (but am not sure) that this way of measuring thread synchronisation mechanisms will not give you correct results, since the timer also tracks the time it took to wait for the mutex. And this does not only depend on the implementation of mutex and semaphores, but also on the way the operating system assigns timeslots to your program. This will probably differ every time you run it. How many times have you tried this and for how long?

Comment: I have ran it like 20 times and the results have been consistent. I'm running this program on an idle core of my controller so that this task wont get interfered by the already running tasks in the current core.

Comment: A semaphore is not normally considered 'lightweight'.  If a thread cannot get the one unit, it has to block on a kernel call, just like a mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutex is probably faster in this case due to the fact that the same task is taking it over and over again with no other task getting involved. My guess is that mutex code is taking a shortcut to enable recursive mutex calls (i.e. the same task takes the same mutex twice). Even though your code is not technically a recursive mutex take, the code probably uses the same shortcut due to the fact that the semaphore owner was not overwritten by any other task taking the semaphore.

In other words you do:

```
1) semTake(semMutex)
2) ++global;
3) semGive(semMutex) // sem owner flag is not changed
4) sameTake(semMutex) // from same task as previous semTake
...
```

Then in step 4 the semTake sees that sem owner == current task id (because the sem owner was set in step 1 and never changed to anything else), so it just marks the semaphore as taken and quickly jumps out.

Of course this is a guess, a quick look at the source code and some vxworks shell breakpoints could confirm this, something I am unable to do because I no longer have access to vxworks.

Additionally look at the semMLib docs for some documentation on the recursive use of mutex.

Comment: Chris, you are awesome. Very nice explanation. Even I believe same thing is happening. It's getting optimized because semOwner is same everytime.  Thanks man !